# Translated file orientations in autodesk-model-derivative

Tags: autodesk-model-derivative

We use a custom ipt template for Autodesk Inventor that has the default orientation as 'Z up'. When we translate files that were created with this template using the autodesk-model-derivative services or even if using the translation tools in the platform services extension in Visual Studio code, the orientation defaults to Front view.

The default orientation(https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkEcm.jpg)

The translated orientation:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQf7T.jpg)

This is a new issue that we haven't see before as we've been running the same way for 3 years now on our site. This has only happened to our files upon a recent move to a new PS account and new bucket setups / translations.

Are there any changes done to the autodesk-model-derivative services that would cause something like his to happen or are we missing something else?

Again, this only happens to any file that was created with our custom Inventor template and then uploaded and translated.

We tested the process of using the standard IPT template to create a file, uploading and translating and it comes across fine.

Comment: I'd be happy to ask the Model Derivative team to see if there have been any changes related to IPT templates that could affect the results you're seeing. But first I need to clarify something: what exactly are you having issues with? Is it the model orientation, or default camera view? Those are two different things.

Comment: Also, it is unlikely that simply creating another APS account would cause these issues. Could it perhaps be that something changed in your custom IPT template?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments under your question, it's not clear whether you're having problems with model orientation or with default camera view. If it's the latter, please note that you can control the camera using various viewer APIs as well. For example, the following code snippet will wait until the initial model data is loaded, and after that it will set the camera to the "top right back" view:

```js
viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.MODEL_ROOT_LOADED_EVENT, async function () {
    const viewCubeExt = await viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.ViewCubeUi');
    viewCubeExt.setViewCube('top right back');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is still unclear to why the conversion is now changing the default view. The problem seems to have stemmed from moving our previously working files from 2020 Inventor to 2022. When we translate to SVF, the orientation is wrong. Very strange issue that has just popped up recently for us. Only happens with Inventor files that use our custom templates with Z 'Up' orientations. I'll setup the viewcube and see what happens. Thanks for the help.